# Someone please explain the basics of VB

Tags: vb.net

I need help with the very basic understanding in plain English for instance :

```
Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click
```

I read this as:

```
Private      (not to be shared or changed) 
Sub          (declares a class) 
Label1       (is the object) 
_            ( I have no idea what the underscore means) 
Click        ( is the event to trigger the object) 
Sender       (The user who clicks the object) 
As           (???? What is this) 
Object       (object)
,            (end of event)
e            ( ?? have no idea) AS (??) 
EventArgs    (?? Not sure) 
Handles      ( i Would assume that has to do with EventArgs) 
Label1.Click (click button).
```

I have read through a lot of books and forums and I just do not get it, I see other people have ask question and get replies like go back and read book, I have tried that.

I need some one that is kind enough to answer these simple question when they come up. Sure I can copy code and create what others have done but the simple core understanding,,, I need help with, any body out there want to help me as these question come up? I have read MSDN forums but again I just do not get it.

Please help me to understand.

Thanks 
Robert

Answer (score 3):

It means:

```
Private      (this method can only be seen in this class) 
Sub          (declares a method without a return value) 
Label1_Click (is the name of the method - the parts are not significant) 
Sender       (The object that raised this event) 
As           (keyword used when declaring the variables and its type) 
Object       (the type of the sender)
,            (separator between parameters)
e            (the object that holds the event values)
EventArgs    (the type of the event values) 
Handles      (Declares that this method is an event handler) 
Label1       (The object that the event is handled from)
.            (The member accessor)
Click        (The event that is handled).
```

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track, but you're reading a little too much significance into certain pieces here.

Label1_Click is a subroutine or a method. Label1_Click is just the name of the method--you could rewrite the line as `Private Sub Hjahsdfkljnag(sender ...`, it would make no difference, at least in theory (I wouldn't recommend it, though).

This looks like a method that's generated when you create a UI in the UI Builder in Visual Studio or equivalent--it's autogenerated to do something when you click on the element Label1 in the UI. So Label1_Click is a descriptive name for a method that handles a click on Label1. The fact that this code was generated automatically is the #1 reason I wouldn't rename it--other code may have been generated elsewhere that references it by this standardized name.

So, stepping through: `Private` means the method is only visible/callable from within the current class--if you reference the class from another file you won't be able to see or use this method.

`Sub` is a subroutine, a method that contains code but does not return anything--it's a way to group code that you want to run together.

`Label1_Click` is the name of the subroutine.

`(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)` are the arguments. Each time the method is to be called, the calling code has to provide an Object (a very generic type) called 'sender' and an EventArgs object (a more specific type, which contains information about an event) called 'e'. These will contain information about the context where the click happened and arguments that were sent--in this case, probably not much of use to you.

`Handles Label1.Click` binds the method to the event--saying that when someone clicks on Label1, this method should run.

Answer (score 2):

A quick explanation:

```
Private      (It is accessible from within class, Read "Access Modifiers" for more info) 
Sub          (Its a sub-routine(does not return value) or function(return value)) 
Label1       (It is the object for which event handling is going to define) 
_            (A convention to separate the `object` and `its event` name) 
Click        (The name of event) 
Sender       (1st argument, name of variable, in this case `The user who clicks the object`) 
As           (Keyword. Works as a bridge to represents the variable and its type) e.g., `dim i as integer`. Here `i` is a variable of type integer.
Object       (Type of sender variable. `object` in this case, can be string, int etc)
,            (Argument separator)
e            (variable of second argument) 
EventArgs    (This represents event specific data, when the event is occured, e.g., on mouse click the position of mouse cursor in x and y co-ordinate) 
Handles      (Keyword) 
Label1.Click (Object with its Event).
```

This can be possibly rectify more, but it should give you an idea at least.

Hope it helps!

Comment: That helps a lot, much easier for me to see broken down this way.

Answer (score 1):

`Private` is the scope of the method, `Label1_Click` is the designer generated method name, `(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)` are the method parameters - or in this case for an event we call it the event signature, `Handles Label1.Click` is the delegate that handles this event. `Sub` is a method type like `Function`, it does not declare a class.

Parameters as based on what type they are and the `As` keyword is just specifing by the `DataType` that follows `(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)`, sender and e are variable names. So `sender` is an Object, `e` is a `EventArgs` class.

Answer (score 1):

Another why to look at this.

Your example is very much related to the [Delegates and Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172879.aspx). In this case the `EventHandler` which is defined as;

```
Public Delegate Sub EventHandler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
```

Imagine this class with a click event of type `EventHandler`:

```
Public Class Button
    Public Event Click As EventHandler
End Class
```

Now, if you are to subscribe to this event you'll need a target defined as an `EventHandler`. Notice, the naming and modifier/access level are irrelevant, but the types are *not*.

```
'                      |                                                          |                                 |
Public/Friend/Private Sub clickOrWhateverYouNameIt(senderOrWhateverYouNameIt As Object, eOrWhateverYouNameIt As EventArgs)
```

**Example**

```
Public Class Form1

    Public Sub Hook()
        AddHandler Me.b.Click, AddressOf Me.MyClick
        'Or
        AddHandler Me.b.Click, Sub(s As Object, ea As EventArgs) MsgBox("Clicked")
    End Sub

    Private Sub MyClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
         MsgBox("Clicked")
    End Sub

    Private b As Button

End Class
```

Or the designer way:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub MyClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles b.Click
         MsgBox("Clicked")
    End Sub

    Private WithEvents b As Button

End Class
```